# Outlook 2013 Use non-default browser to open links

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, browser, microsoft-outlook-2013

There are some old questions regarding this, but they don't (or may) pertain to Outlook 2013.

Is there any functionality to specify which browser Outlook 2013 uses to open links? I use Chrome for browsing, and the items I receive through e-mail often require IE so I'd like all links in Outlook 2013 to open in IE.

This is a corporate machine, so I can't install any additional plugins or software.

Comment: The question is pre Outlook 2013. The first solution suggests installing additional software (not an option), the second says that it only works with the default browser. I edited the first sentence in the question.

Comment: New features may be added in new versions of software... Do you have anything constructive to add?

Comment: I have a constructive suggestion: since the other question does not specifically ask about earlier versions of Outlook, it would simplify things to "refresh" that old question and put any new version information in an additional answer.  I see your rep is kinda low, so I've actually done that for you - I upvoted, commented, and edited the old question (after peer review, the edit should bump the question back at the top of the list).  Once that happens, I'd encourage you to delete this question (or ask a moderator to mark it duplicate).

Comment: I withdraw my comment(s)